# Python serial port read delay

Tags: python, avr, pyserial

I'm playing around with this serial module in python. I have a little problem with it. I want my script to get a char from the console send it to an AVR board, and read back the response.
Everytime I read from the USB port, and print it out, I see the previous result. Why's that? 
For example:

I write 5 
I read nothing
I write 6
I read 5

```
import serial
import sys, time

port=serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

i=0
tmp = 0
while True:

    tmp=raw_input('send: ')

    port.write(tmp)
    port.flushOutput()

    print port.read(1)
    port.flushInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#classes): "Writes are blocking by default, unless writeTimeout is set. For possible values refer to the list for timeout above." Try setting `writeTimeout=0` as well in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably receiving a single unexpected byte on startup - either the microcontroller is sending it, or it might be noise from connecting a plug. As you are only reading a single byte for each string transmitted, you will always be off by one.

Instead of `port.read(1)`, try:

```
while True:

    tmp=raw_input('send: ')

    port.write(tmp)
    port.flushOutput()

    print port.read(port.inWaiting())
    port.flushInput()
```

This would also have happened if your typed in more than one character at the input prompt.